# Initializing a String without an extra line

Tags: java, string

Do you know how you would initialize a string without creating an extra line? I am printing to an output file.

```
public String speedUp(int MPH) {
    String output ="";
    if(!moving){
        output+="\tError: Train is not moving";
    }
    else{this.speed += MPH;}
    return output;
}
```

That is what i have currently and when I view the output file i get an extra line every time there is no error.

Below is my current output:

```
SPEEDUP 20

SLOWDOWN 5
```

Below is how I call the method.

```
out.println(speedup(MPH));
```

'out' is defined as my print writer.

Comment: Can you add the output?

Comment: Where do you call speedUp?

Comment: do you `println(output)` ??

Answer (score 1):

I guess you print to file every `speedUp` result.

You can change it and print to file only if `speedUp` result is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

How you are printing the String? 
 If you are using println it will create an empty line. Use print() if you have a new line character in your String by itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String speedUp(int MPH) {    
    if(!moving){
        return "\tError: Train is not moving";
    }
    else
    {
      this.speed += MPH;
      return "";
    }
}
```

And on the call of `SpeedUP()` ignore empty strings.

Alternatively consider refacttoring your code toeither return a boolean, and once false is returned you write the string to the file, otherwise ignore it. Or throw an exception if the train is not moving which you cath of the calling mthode and write the exception message to the file.